# Лучшая практика для вывода продуктов интернет-магазина

Tags: php, mvc, best-practice

Пишу интернет-магазин на php. Написал три контроллера:

1. ProductController для вывода информации об одном продукте. URL выглядит так: http:// название-сайта.ком/product/алиас-продукта
2. ProductsController для вывода списка всех продуктов. URL выглядит так: http:// название-сайта.ком/products
3. CategoryController для вывода списка всех продуктов из определенной категории. URL выглядит так: http:// название-сайта.ком/category/имя-категории

Думал сделать так: один контроллер для вывода всех продуктов и категорий(чтоб URL выглядел типа: http:// название-сайта.ком/products/имя-категории) или например объединить контроллер для вывода одного товара и всех(чтоб URL выглядел типа: http:// название-сайта.ком/products/алиас-продукта).

Вопрос такой: что является лучшей практикой? как сделать правильно? не скупиться на контроллеры и делать их много или лучше некоторые объединить? как правильно со стороны чистого кода?

Comment: Если идти по шаблону MVC, то правильнее объединять в одном контроллере работу с одной сущностью. Но есть немного другой подход - это разделение контроллера на действия (action), где в каждом классе описывается только конкретное действие над сущностью. Многое зависит от способа маршрутизации в вашем проекте и внедрения зависимостей.

Comment: По Rest все логично, контроллеры не обьеденяй  , может в дальнейшем логика поменяется и т.п.

Comment: Cпасибо большое за ваши ответы!